# "user" CIFS mounts not supported - fedora 30

Tags: mount, fedora, samba, cifs, setuid

I have a number of smb v1 shares. *(I know that smbv1 is old and vulnerable but I can't change it)*
Because of the old smb protocol, I cannot use nautilus to open then. Instead, I used fstab entries to mount them. The entries in `/etc/fstab` look like this:

```
//smbserver/folder /media/user/smbserver/folder cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=1.0,noauto,user 0 0
```

On a Mint 19 machine, this worked like a charm, but on a new Fedora 30 installation, I only get the following error:

```
$ mount /media/user/smbserver/folder
This program is not installed setuid root -  "user" CIFS mounts not supported.
```

I already tried to set the suid bit for `/usr/bin/mount`, but this did not change anything.

How can I mount the smb shares on Fedora 30?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, found out myself.

The following programs needed to have the *suid* bit set (`sudo chmod u+s /bin/...`):

```
/bin/mount
/bin/umount
/usr/sbin/mount.cifs
```

Some Distros do this by default. However, there seems to be discussion about the security (s-bit is always problematic).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This works for NFS as well.

Comment: `sudo chmod u+s /bin/mount /bin/umount /usr/sbin/mount.cifs`

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check that the file /home/user/.smbcredentials is accessible to you. I created mine with root which caused me issues.

But what ultimately helped me solve the issue was your advice on setting the suid bit on /usr/sbin/mount.cifs --> thank you!

EDIT: as my answer is being questioned, this is relevant information, because a missing access right to a credentials file can cause the error described in the OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).